# how to remove the "i" symbol at header when read csv in R?

Tags: r

I have the data frame as:

```
                                 15_24years      25_34years    35_44years   45+years
sleep and personal activity          11              10            10          12
sleeping                              8               7             7           6
personal care                         0.5             1             1           3
eating                                2.5             2             2           3
paid working                          3               8             8           5
schooling                             6               2             1           1
others                                4               4             5           6
```

but when I use `time<-read.csv("time.csv")`and `view(time)`,I have result as [image: result]

how can I remove the i and just leave as blank and remove X but just leave 15_24years?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Could be the Byte Order Mark (BOM).  Try `read.csv("time.csv", fileEncoding="UTF-8-BOM", check.names = FALSE)`

Comment: Can you provide link to the original `time.csv` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `check.names = FALSE` to avoid applying the `make.names/make.unique` from modifying the non-standard column names i.e. column names that don't start with a letter.  Also, specify the first column as row names

```
time <- read.csv("time.csv", check.names = FALSE, row.names = 1)
```

-checking

```
View(time)
```

[image]

Comment: When I add "activitytype" as the name of first column, the i symbol still here, but I cannot use row.names=1. What should I do with this situation? Thanks!

Comment: @SHIRLEEN then just leave the `row.names = NULL` or simply don't use it as it will correctly judge the row.names to default case because your data have all proper column names

Comment: Is not working. I named the first column as "activitytype", but when i view the data, it is still shows "i..activitytype" .

Comment: @SHIRLEEN Have you used `check.names = FALSE`. I suspect that you may have some spaces before the `"activitytype"` i.e. `"  activitytype"`

Comment: I tried, even worse, it became to i>>?activitytype. There are no space.

Comment: @SHIRLEEN the `activityType` by itself is a standard name.  Its not clear why it is having a problem.  Can you rename it again.  Did you copied this from any website i.e. it may be that the encoding is not correct

Comment: @SHIRLEEN Also, try to specify the `encoding`

Comment: It is not copy, I type it by myself.

Comment: @SHIRLEEN I tried by adding activityType and it is working fine for me though

Comment: @SHIRLEEN Can you also try `readr::read_csv("time.csv")`